# How to fix "Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class (not found)LinearLayout" in Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I'm trying to build an app which will have a Settings page. I searched for the best way to build a Preference page and now I'm trying to build it using `PreferenceFragmentCompat`. I found some tutorials on the web and tried to put it together, but the problem happens when I try to run the app. The app builds without errors, but when it deploys I get an error

```
Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class (not found)LinearLayout
```

which happens in `AddPreferencesFromResource()` function. It doesn't matter if I define `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` in `Main.axml`, the error is always the same.

I tried cleaning and rebuilding project, restarting VS and finally I managed to get it to work using `FragmentManager` and `PreferenceFragment` in another app instead of `SupportFragmentManager` and `PreferenceFragmentCompat`, but I would prefer for it to work with latter options.

This is the code from a simple empty app where I reproduced the problem:

`MainActivity.cs`

```cs
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;

namespace App1
{
    [Activity(Label = "App1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MyTheme")]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction transaction = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.pref_container, new SettingsFragment()).Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

`SettingsFragment.cs`

```cs
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.Preferences;

namespace App1
{
    class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat
    {
        public override void OnCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, string rootKey)
        {
            AddPreferencesFromResource(Resource.Layout.Preference);
        }
    }
}
```

`Main.axml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/pref_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`Preference.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <CheckBoxPreference
          android:key="checkbox"
          android:summary="Tap to check if on or off"
          android:title="Checkbox Preference" />
  <RingtonePreference
          android:key="ringtone"
          android:showDefault="true"
          android:showSilent="true"
          android:summary="Pick a ringtone you like"
          android:title="Ringtone Preference" />
  <EditTextPreference
          android:dialogTitle="Enter a text"
          android:key="text"
          android:summary="Click to show a text entry dialog"
          android:title="EditText Preference" />
  <SwitchPreference
          android:key="switch"
          android:title="Switch Preference"
          android:summary="Click to switch on or off"
          android:defaultValue="true"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

`Styles.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

I want to crate Settings page using PreferenceFragmentCompat. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: It might be due to dependency problem. Try to close the VS and delete the folder `bin` and `obj` in your project ,then restart it and rebuild your project .

Comment: Hi @LucasZhang-MSFT, I have tried your suggestion and the problem still persists. Anything else that could cause this?

Comment: Just curious, but I also get Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.preference.LinearLayout" error in Output. Surely V7.Preferences doesn't contain any LinearLayout?

Comment: Open the nuget manager in android project and check if android.support.v7.support has been installed . Or you can share your sample and I will check it on my side .

Comment: I checked the NuGet manager and the android.support.v7.support is installed. I also shared the sample project in One Drive so you can try it on your machine: https://ininsi-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/erik_horvat_inin_si/EUjgBiQKlYBCve1Iq4Eez4cBaBSoMAAvI_s8PJr4sLoWKA?e=839ydK

Comment: It works fine on my side (I delete the folder bin and obj before build it) ,so I suggest you can create a new project and move your code to it and check if the issue is still existing .